Why do I not receive a response from $aws/certificates/create/json/accepted or rejected when I publish to topic $aws/certificates/create/json?
I have an esp32 device that has a certificate I generated in AWS to be used as a claim certificate. The esp32 connects to AWS fine and allows me to subscribe to the accepted and rejected topics. When I publish to the $aws/certificates/create/json topic a new certificate is generated in aws with pending activation but the esp32 receives no message back from AWS on either the accepted or rejected topic.
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <SPIFFS.h>  // For saving credentials
#include <Secrets.h>

// WiFi credentials
const char* ssid = "";
const char* password = "";

const char* awsCertTopic = "$aws/certificates/create/json";                                                     // MQTT topic for creating new Certificate
const char* awsCertAccepted = "$aws/certificates/create/json/accepted";                                         // MQTT topic for new Certificate Accepted
const char* awsCertRejected = "$aws/certificates/create/json/rejected";                                         // MQTT topic for new Certificate Rejected
const char* awsFleetTopic = "$aws/provisioning-templates/DrainAlert_FleetTemplate/provision/json";              // MQTT topic for fleet provisioning
const char* awsFleetAccepted = "$aws/provisioning-templates/DrainAlert_FleetTemplate/provision/json/accepted";  // MQTT topic for fleet provisioning Accepted
const char* awsFleetRejected = "$aws/provisioning-templates/DrainAlert_FleetTemplate/provision/json/rejected";  // MQTT topic for fleet provisioning Rejected
const char* awsTestTopic = "ji/tp";

// Time Sync details
const char* ntpServer = "pool.ntp.org";
const long gmtOffset_sec = 0;
const int daylightOffset_sec = 3600;

// WiFiClientSecure for secure MQTT connection
WiFiClientSecure wifiClient;
PubSubClient mqttClient(wifiClient);

void setupTime() {
  configTime(gmtOffset_sec, daylightOffset_sec, ntpServer);
  Serial.println("Waiting for NTP time sync...");
  while (!time(nullptr)) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("\nTime synchronized");
}

// Function to save the new certificate and private key to SPIFFS
void saveCredentials(const char* cert, const char* privateKey) {
  if (!SPIFFS.begin(true)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to mount file system");
    return;
  }

  // Save certificate
  File certFile = SPIFFS.open("/deviceCert.pem", FILE_WRITE);
  if (certFile) {
    certFile.print(cert);
    certFile.close();
    Serial.println("Saved new certificate");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Failed to open cert file for writing");
  }

  // Save private key
  File keyFile = SPIFFS.open("/privateKey.pem", FILE_WRITE);
  if (keyFile) {
    keyFile.print(privateKey);
    keyFile.close();
    Serial.println("Saved new private key");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Failed to open key file for writing");
  }

  SPIFFS.end();
}

// Callback function to handle MQTT messages
void mqttCallback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived on topic: ");
  Serial.println(topic);
  // Convert payload to a string
  String payloadStr = String((char*)payload).substring(0, length);
  Serial.print("Payload: " + payloadStr);

  // Handle the provisioning response
  if (strcmp(topic, "$aws/certificates/create/json/accepted") == 0) {
    Serial.println("Provisioning successful. Saving new credentials...");

    // Parse JSON to extract certificate and private key
    String newCert = extractCertFromPayload(payloadStr);
    String newPrivateKey = extractPrivateKeyFromPayload(payloadStr);

    // Save the new credentials
    saveCredentials(newCert.c_str(), newPrivateKey.c_str());
  }
}

String extractCertFromPayload(String payload) {
  StaticJsonDocument<1024> doc;
  deserializeJson(doc, payload);
  return doc["certificatePem"].as<String>();
}

String extractPrivateKeyFromPayload(String payload) {
  StaticJsonDocument<1024> doc;
  deserializeJson(doc, payload);
  return doc["privateKey"].as<String>();
}

void connectToWiFi() {
  Serial.print("Connecting to WiFi...");
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected!");
}

void connectToMQTT() {
  wifiClient.setCACert(awsRootCA);
  wifiClient.setCertificate(claimCert);
  wifiClient.setPrivateKey(claimPrivateKey);

  mqttClient.setServer(awsEndpoint, awsPort);
  mqttClient.setCallback(mqttCallback);

  while (!mqttClient.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Connecting to AWS IoT...");
    if (mqttClient.connect("DnAtClient")) {
      Serial.println("Connected!");

      // Subscribe to provisioning response topics
      mqttClient.subscribe(awsCertAccepted);
      if (mqttClient.subscribe(awsCertAccepted)) {
        Serial.println("Successfully subscribed to awsCertificateAccepted topic");
      } else {
        Serial.println("Failed to subscribe to awsCertificateAccepted topic");
      }

      mqttClient.subscribe(awsCertRejected);
      if (mqttClient.subscribe(awsCertRejected)) {
        Serial.println("Successfully subscribed to awsCertificateRejected topic");
      } else {
        Serial.println("Failed to subscribe to awsCertificateRejected topic");
      }

      mqttClient.subscribe(awsFleetAccepted);
      if (mqttClient.subscribe(awsFleetAccepted)) {
        Serial.println("Successfully subscribed to awsFleetAccepted topic");
      } else {
        Serial.println("Failed to subscribe to awsFleetAccepted topic");
      }

      mqttClient.subscribe(awsFleetRejected);
      if (mqttClient.subscribe(awsFleetRejected)) {
        Serial.println("Successfully subscribed to awsFleetRejected topic");
      } else {
        Serial.println("Failed to subscribe to awsFleetRejected topic");
      }

      mqttClient.subscribe(awsTestTopic);
      if (mqttClient.subscribe(awsTestTopic)) {
        Serial.println("Successfully subscribed to awsTestTopic topic");
      } else {
        Serial.println("Failed to subscribe to awsTestTopic topic");
      }

    } else {
      Serial.print("Failed to connect, rc=");
      Serial.print(mqttClient.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void triggerCertCreation() {
  String payload = "{}";  
  mqttClient.publish(awsCertTopic, payload.c_str());
  Serial.println("New Certificate Request Sent...");
}

void reconnect() {
  while (!mqttClient.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    if (mqttClient.connect("ESP32Client")) {
      Serial.println("connected");

      mqttClient.subscribe(awsFleetAccepted);
      mqttClient.subscribe(awsFleetRejected);
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(mqttClient.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, INPUT);
  connectToWiFi();
  delay(250);
  setupTime();
  delay(250);
  connectToMQTT();
  delay(1000);
  triggerCertCreation();
}

void loop() {
  if (!mqttClient.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  } else {
    digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
  }

  if (digitalRead(9) == LOW){
    Serial.println("Sending message to get Cert topic...  ");
    triggerCertCreation();

  }
  mqttClient.loop();
  delay(250);
}

Policy where My-ID is replaced with my account id without the greater/less than symbols.
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:Publish",
        "iot:Receive"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:<My-ID>:topic/$aws/certificates/create/json",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:<My-ID>:topic/$aws/provisioning-templates/DrainAlert_FleetTemplate/provision/json"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:<My-ID>:topicfilter/$aws/certificates/create/*",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:<My-ID>:topicfilter/$aws/provisioning-templates/DrainAlert_FleetTemplate/provision/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Receive",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:<My-ID>:topic/$aws/certificates/create/json/accepted",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:<My-ID>:topic/$aws/certificates/create/json/rejected",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:<My-ID>:topic/$aws/provisioning-templates/DrainAlert_FleetTemplate/provision/json/accepted",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:<My-ID>:topic/$aws/provisioning-templates/DrainAlert_FleetTemplate/provision/json/rejected"
      ]
    }
  ]
}


I have tried not subscribing as the documentation says that it isn't necessary, but neither way will work.

And how does the output to the serial look like? And when you reconnect, you only subscribe to two topics and with a different client name.

my output:
06:48:57.850 -> Time synchronized
06:48:58.128 -> Connecting to AWS IoT...Connected!
06:48:59.229 -> Successfully subscribed to awsCertificateAccepted topic
06:48:59.229 -> Successfully subscribed to awsCertificateRejected topic
06:48:59.229 -> Successfully subscribed to awsFleetAccepted topic
06:48:59.229 -> Successfully subscribed to awsFleetRejected topic
06:49:00.242 -> New Certificate Request Sent...
after that there is nothing else. I have been able to send and receive messages on other topics when i change the policy to allow it to do so. i never reconnect

I have a similar post on Reddit in which someone provided a link with example code specifically for esp32. I was missing setBufferSize in my callback function and this fixed my problem so now I receive new certificate information from AWS on ESP32. EXAMPLE CODE

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
